# XAML support for local-name() in XPath

Tags: xaml, xpath

I'd like to bind to the element name of a node in my `XmlDataProvider`. I can't seem to get local-name() to work within my XPath expression. Does XAML support local-name()?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=local-name()}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to do exactly the same thing and am pretty sure it is not supported in a single step.

The [Binding.XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx) help says
The [XmlNode::SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes.aspx) method handles the XPath expressions from the XPath property. XPath functions are not supported.

**However**

You can work around it using a bit of a hack - you need a container around the element to provide a DataContext which is the result of your XPath and then you can query the LocalName property of that context object using **Path**, such as in my working example:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="1" 
    DataContext="{Binding XPath=r:Result/r:LIC1}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

which I'd originally been trying to achieve with:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="1" 
    Text="{Binding XPath=r:Result/r:LIC1/local-name\(\)}" />
```

Comment: The quote you provided from the documentation seems to be key: "XPath functions are not supported." I wonder why a limitation like that is not in bigger letters?