# How to bind the xml element name to a ListView column in WPF XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, xpath

I have XML data similar to the example below and I am trying to bind it to a ListView.  I am having trouble binding the element name, which is the brand of the car in the example.  I have found out from this post [Xaml Support for Local Name in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638694/xaml-support-for-local-name-in-xpath) that xaml doesn't support xpath function names.  Therefore, local-name() doesn't work.  But there got to be a way to do this...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="DataSource">
      <x:XData>
        <Cars xmlns="">
          <Data>
            <Honda Year="2012"
                   Color="Red"
                   Model="Accord" />
            <Subuar Year="2008"
                    Color="Blue"
                    Model="Outback" />
            <Ford Year="2000"
                  Color="Black"
                  Model="Focus" />
          </Data>
        </Cars>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Cars/Data/*}"
            DataContext="{StaticResource DataSource}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=???}"
                        Header="Brand" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Year}"
                        Header="Year" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Color}"
                        Header="Color" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Model}"
                        Header="Model" />
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Since it is a one way binding,  I wrote a converter for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the normal `Binding.Path` is should bind to the properties of the `DataContext` object which should be an [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) so just try `{Binding Name}`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can bind to an element name, is would require the "name()" or "local-name()" XPath functions, but they aren't supported in Xaml.  You can work around it, see this URL:

[XAML support for local-name() in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638694/xaml-support-for-local-name-in-xpath)

But this does work and isn't as ugly as a hack-ar, just requires a slightly different XML input:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="DataSource">
        <x:XData>
            <Cars xmlns="">
                <Data>
                    <Car Brand="Honda" Year="2012" Color="Red" Model="Accord"/>
                    <Car Brand="Subuaru" Year="2008" Color="Blue" Model="Outback"/>
                    <Car Brand="Ford" Year="2000" Color="Black" Model="Focus"/>
                </Data>
            </Cars>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Cars/Data/*}" DataContext="{StaticResource DataSource}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Brand}" Header="Brand"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Year}" Header="Year"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Color}" Header="Color"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Model}" Header="Model"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: The data comes from a service provider and I don't have control over its format.