# XAML ListView Gridview Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

New to WPF and I have a listview with a gridview in it.

I want to bind the ID column to the text property of a textbox, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the individual grid columns for the selected items

the code looks like the following

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          SelectionChanged="onSelectedIndexChange" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlDoc}, Path=xmdModule}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=//*[@ID]}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID"  Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Attributes[ID].Value}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Attributes[name].Value}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listView1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           TextAlignment="Left" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can try to **EITHER** set `SelectedValuePath` of the `ListView` to the `ID` attribute :</s>

```
<ListView .....
          SelectedValuePath="Attributes[ID].Value"
          .....>
```

**OR** try to bind the `TextBox` to `SelectedItem.Attributes[ID].Value` instead :

```
<TextBlock ......
           Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Attributes[ID].Value, ElementName=listView1}"
           ....../>
```

Comment: The top suggestion did not function, though I think I understand why. The bottom one worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, scratched the top suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
where AttributeName is element attribute which you want to bind.

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@AttributeName}" Header="AttributeName" />
```

refer this link for reference [How to bind the xml element name to a ListView column in WPF XAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638237/how-to-bind-the-xml-element-name-to-a-listview-column-in-wpf-xaml-file)

Tried and its working fine.